# Best solution implementing "basic" bbcode with php

Tags: php, bbcode

I'm writing a board software which have basic styling such as bold, italic, underline, strikethrough. I use the bbcode syntax for them. For full bbcode support/compatible, I will need regex, but for that basic styling, I found that I can do str_replace with [b] [i] [/close-tag]... replaced with    **after** I do a htmlspecialchars() sanitize. Could there be a problem with that?

Comment: This is called **markdown**

Comment: But anyway, if you want to stick with this ancient cumbersome technology, you may want to check existing answers

Comment: I don't implement markdown. Markdown is something "\_i\_ \_\_u\_\_ \*\*b\*\*". [b] [/b] is bbcode.

Comment: Markdown is far superior to bbcode. Typing `*b*` is just natural, as opposed to `[b]b[/b]`. Nobody uses bb nowadays for a reason.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm asking is it a good idea to just str_replace [b] with <b>?

Comment: And I told you already that you may want to check existing answers.